# Subclass constructor calling wrong __init__

Tags: python

So I am having some trouble with inheritance in python. I have two classes. The first is

```
class Base1DHeatEquation:
    def __init__(self, alpha, final_time, time_discrete):
       self.alpha = alpha
       self.final_time = final_time
       self.time_discrete = time_discrete

       #Additional Functions which aren't causing a problem
```

and the second is a class which inherits the first

```
class IntialValueTest1DHE(Base1DHeatEquation):
   def __init__(self, alpha, final_time, time_discrete,intialValues,\
             x_discrete ,noise):
        super(IntialValueTest1DHE,self).__init__(self, alpha, final_time, time_discrete)
        self.intialValues = intialValues

   #Additional Functions which aren't causing a problem
```

The problem is when I trying to create an IntialValueTest1DHE object, I get the following

```
>>> import HeatEquation1D as he #The File where both classes are stored
>>> temp = he.IntialValueTest1DHE(1,1,100,np.sin,100,0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 4 arguments (7 given)
```

It seems like object creation is trying to access the **init** from the parent class in stead of the child class and I am not sure how to fix that.

Comment: Don't you **want** to call the parent class __init__ function? You want to so that you can set up your alpha, final_time, and discrete_time variables

Comment: I do call the parent class __init__ inside the IntialValueTest1DHE __init__ using super. However I want to create the IntialValueTest1DHE object from its own __init__.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to add "self" to super() declaration.  Also, you should use "new style" classes:

```
class Base1DHeatEquation(object):
    def __init__(self, alpha, final_time, time_discrete):
       self.alpha = alpha
       self.final_time = final_time
       self.time_discrete = time_discrete

class IntialValueTest1DHE(Base1DHeatEquation):
    def __init__(self, alpha, final_time, time_discrete,intialValues,
           x_discrete ,noise):
        super(IntialValueTest1DHE,self).__init__(alpha, final_time, time_discrete)
        self.intialValues = intialValues
```

Comment: Changing that had no effect on the error. Still getting the same error message.

Comment: This code works for me if I cut and paste it into the terminal.  Maybe you aren't reloading the module properly or there is an old version in your PYTHONPATH